# Creating a project list for CV using moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I have a CV created with moderncv. Now I need a project list(IT) that looks similar to my CV but it doesn't look that good. I tried to make a letter in moderncv with sections for each projects and used the itemize environement for longer(>1 sentence) descriptions. Even the title looked bad.

I tried also to create a scrartcl document with sections and the itemize environement. It had a nice title but it doesn't look good at all.

Sample 1:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{relsize} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.5cm}


\firstname{My} %Vorname
\familyname{Name} % Nachname

\recipient{\vspace{15ex}\mbox{Projectlist}}{} 
\date{\today} 
\opening{} 
\closing{} 
\address{Street 1}{1234 City}
\phone{0555/55 55 55}
\email{name@mail.com}

\begin{document}
\makelettertitle % Print letter title

\section{Project A}
\begin{itemize}
\item Description 
\item Description 
\end{itemize}

\section{Project B}
Description

\end{document}
```

Sample2:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx} %%Zum Laden von Grafiken
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}

\author{My Name}
\title{Projectlist}

\maketitle
\section*{Project A}
Description

\section*{Project B}
\begin{itemize}
\item Description
\item Description
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[This CV looks like mine](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/moderncv-cv-and-cover-letter)

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Droider

Comment: Perhaps you could add a sample document and tell us what you would like to change on it. As it stands this is a bit vague I think.

Comment: You want something that looks similar to your CV, but how is your CV?

Comment: what do you need exactly, color? centering title?...

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to make a good looking Project list for my CV. How did you do it or how would you do it?  Is there another class for creating a project list? I need something official that looks good. My tries look very bad in my opinion.